# SQL UPDATE deletes record

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server

For some reason UPDATE is deleting the record in my SQL Server database instead of updating it. I have tried only passing one variable (and changed it different individual fields) and it deletes 100%. I also have made sure there was data being passed so I'm not dealing with a DBNull issue. My SO and google searches keep coming up with the delete then add row process for updating records. What might be going on here?

```
protected void grdvMyEntries_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
{
    string Task = (grdvMyEntries.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("ddlTasks") as DropDownList).SelectedItem.Value;

    string Code = (grdvMyEntries.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("ddlPayrollCodes") as DropDownList).SelectedItem.Value;
    DateTime strDate = Convert.ToDateTime((grdvMyEntries.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txtDateEdit") as TextBox).Text.Trim());
    string TimeIn = (grdvMyEntries.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txtTimeInEdit") as TextBox).Text.Trim();
    string TimeOut = (grdvMyEntries.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txtTimeOutEdit") as TextBox).Text.Trim();
    string ItemNo = (grdvMyEntries.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txtItemNo") as TextBox).Text.Trim();
    string WO = (grdvMyEntries.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txtWO") as TextBox).Text.Trim();
    string WIP = (grdvMyEntries.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txtWIP") as TextBox).Text.Trim();
    string Note = (grdvMyEntries.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txtNote") as TextBox).Text.Trim();
    string TimeID = grdvMyEntries.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Value.ToString();
    string strConnString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MAFapp"].ConnectionString;

    string strTmp = "Date:" + strDate + "|TimeIn:" + TimeIn + "|TimeOut:" + TimeOut + "|WIP:" + WIP + "|WO:" + WO + "|ItemNo:" + ItemNo + "|Task:" + Task + "|Code:" + Code + "|Note:" + Note + "|WHERE TimeID:" + TimeID;
    Debug.Print(strTmp);

    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strConnString))
    {
        string query = "UPDATE Time SET [Date]=@Date, [TimeIn]=@TimeIn, [TimeOut]=@TimeOut, [WIP]=@WIP, [WO]=@WO, [ItemNo]=@ItemNo, [Task]=@Task, [Code]=@Code, [Note]=@Note WHERE [TimeID]=@TimeID";
        Debug.WriteLine(query);
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query))
        {
            cmd.Connection = con;
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TimeID", TimeID);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Date", strDate);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TimeIn", TimeIn);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TimeOut", TimeOut);
            if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(WIP.Trim()))
            {
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@WIP", WIP).Value = Convert.DBNull; ;
            }
            else
            {
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@WIP", WIP);
            }
            if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(WO.Trim()))
            {
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@WO", WO).Value = Convert.DBNull; ;
            }
            else
            {
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@WO", WO);
            }
            if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(ItemNo.Trim()))
            {
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ItemNo", ItemNo).Value = Convert.DBNull; ;
            }
            else
            {
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ItemNo", ItemNo);
            }
            if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Task.Trim()))
            {
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Task", Task).Value = Convert.DBNull; ;
            }
            else
            {
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Task", Task);
            }
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Code", Code);

            if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Note.Trim()))
            {
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Note", Note).Value = Convert.DBNull; ;
            }
            else
            {
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Note", Note);
            }


            con.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();
            tblSummary.DataBind();
            grdvMyEntries.DataBind();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you trigger on your table? If no, it's impossible delete a record with an update. Maybe you have some fields to NULL and your check query doesn't recognize them

Comment: have you checked the database table are the rows missing (as joe said it cant be deleted by that update itself)? might it be that your update makes the rows not apear due to a "faulty" select in some other place?

Comment: There is no possibilities to delete using Update statement unless you have trigger on table as @Joe Taras mention.

Comment: Interesting what you guys are saying, and I'm following. However, When I add a record, it adds in the database. Then when I do the UPDATE, it deletes the record in the database. There is a debug line in there and I have watched the data to make sure it is passing correctly into the parameters. Also what is weird, is that it is deleting just that one record (thank goodness).

Comment: There are no triggers (as in updatePanel trigger). Otherwise, the event trigger is OnRowUpdating.

Comment: @Beengie You  need to check the trigger in SQL Server.

Comment: SQL Server management studio triggers folder is empty for the associated database

Comment: @Beengie You need to check it from Table `Time`

Comment: Ran the SELECT from @StackUser and it came up with no triggers.

Comment: @Beengie Go to SQL Server management, expand databases => database name => Tables > Time > Triggers

Comment: That's what I did before I tried the code below.

Comment: @Beengie Try running the same query on SQL managament studio directly. Do you get the same result ? Check how many lines of "number of rows affected" you get

Comment: I ran it within SQL mgmt studio

Answer (score 2):

Update won't delete rows from a table. The only possibility would be trigger on your tables. Please run this query to find list of triggers and its text.

```
USE ChangeThisToDatabaseName
GO

SELECT so.NAME
    ,TEXT
FROM sysobjects so
    ,syscomments sc
WHERE type = 'TR'
    AND so.id = sc.id
    AND TEXT LIKE '%Time%'
```

Note:If there is no triggers on your table then please ensure Is there any records exist based on your filter before running the update.

Answer (score 0):

A while ago, when I try to instert data to a table, data is being recorded but after two seconds from insterting the record was deleted automatically. There was no trigger or something like that. Then I have observed the table and I found an indexing problem. I have rebuilt that index and problem has been solved. If you do not have huge data in your table I suggest you to try to rebuild your indexes or recreate them.